# Android Eclipse findViewByID with programmatically CheckBox

Tags: java, android, eclipse, checkbox, findviewbyid

I create a few CheckBoxes programatically like this:

```
    public int cb_id = 1000;

    public void create_cb()
    {

            CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(this);
            cb1.setText("My CheckBox");
            cb1.setId(cb_id);

            LinearLayout ll_checkbox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_checkbox);

            ll_checkbox.addView(cb1);

    }
```

This work's fine for me, but I can't find the CheckBox with the ID...

```
    public void find_cb()
    {

            CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(cb_id);

            String content = cb1.getText().toString();

    }
```

This is not working, the app is closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code:

```
public void find_cb()
{
     LinearLayout ll_checkbox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_checkbox);
     CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) ll_checkbox.findViewById(cb_id);
     String content = cb1.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure about my answer @DigveshPatel, i just wait for seeing that maybe useful for OP, i'm gonna delete that, because i'm not sure this work properly ,

Comment: dear your answers is ri8 but need some clarification so he/she get idea for that +1 for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use

```
CheckBox cb1;
```

as **Global** like `public int cb_id = 1000;` and inside `create_cb()` method just use `cb1 = new CheckBox(this);` and `find_cb()` method like below

```
public void find_cb()
{
   String content = cb1.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the number of CheckBoxes always depends on the user.