# How to change button label on runtime?

Tags: android, button

I'm using a button to create new button's on runtime but the new buttons created have predefined label i.e. `btn1.setText("New");`. Is there any way so that once buttons created on runtime there label can be modified or change to some other label like instead of **New** it can be "Click", "mouse", "clothing" but while application is running.
code to create button:

```
if(v == add){
        Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("New");
        btn1.setId(34);     
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mDialog();
            }
        });
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        ll.addView(btn1, lp);
        count++;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", count);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

And I'm using shared preferences to store previous created buttons

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    count=prefs.getInt("count", 0);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        final Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mDialog(myButton.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        myButton.setId(34);
        myButton.setText("New");
        myButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog mdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                mdialog.setTitle("Change Button Label");
                mdialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info); 
                mdialog.setMessage("Enter new Button label  to change");
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

                mdialog.setView(input);
                mdialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Change",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        myButton.setText(input.getText());
                    }
                });

                mdialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", 
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Label not Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                mdialog.show(); 

                return true;    // <- set to true
            }
        });
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
    }
```

Comment: yes you can, see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497816/android-eclipse-findviewbyid-with-programmatically-checkbox/21497854#21497854, declare your button and use `setText` method for that.

Comment: `setText` does not work?

Comment: can you take the label input from the user? or from where will this dynamic label text come

Comment: Store all the labels in ArrayList and get them according to your requirement. or increment conditions

Comment: @user2450263 from the user means user will be able to change button label as per his requirement.

Comment: @Henry No.. 'setText' provide predefined label to button

Comment: @user3172071 : yes....you can call the setText() for that button after taking user's input, i don't think there is anything else to that

Comment: what is your mean about "I want the user will be able to name the button while running application"? where user put name ?

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan what I want is that the user can rename button

Comment: where ? please describe better.

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan the above code creates button on runtime with the label "New" .the thing I want is that user will be able to replace "New" with any name (for e.g. click this, ok, cancel, products etc.)

Comment: ok, but where ? like you declare one option in menu that when user clicked on that show one EditText to user and you change the text, or want if clicked on Button user can change text or what ?

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan yes that thing I want to ask as I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you can set this option on `longClick` of your button

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan can you please provide necessary code if possible.

Comment: you just need setOnLongClickListener for your button, then in that pop up one dialog that have rename title and one EditText for new text and 2 button for cancel and approve and in approve listener set new text on button

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan please check my edits. I'm using dialogbox in which I'm providing EditText, but still after rename button when I reopen application the button label is still set to "New".

Comment: if you want save your value after exiting on your app, you need save the value, so use `sharedPreference `to do that

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan I'm still using shared preferences to save previously created buttons. and in activity declaring shared preference= null. so can you tell me how I can save the value of new button label

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to:

```
mButton.setText("WhatEver");
```

you not need to add the Button again to the layout

To save the Text if you want to show it all the time also if the app is closed you must use Shared Preferences like:

```
SharedPreference preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferece(this);
```

Now if the user change the text do this

```
Editor edit = preference.edit();
edit.putString("key",mButton.getText().toString());
edit.commit();
```

Now you had saved the string in the preferences with the key "key"

Now remove the line where you set the Button text to "New" with:

```
mButton.setText(preference.getString("key","New");
```

Thats it :)

Comment: but this need to define in code. But I want the user will be able to name the button while running application

Comment: Then add somewhere an Edittext which sets the text of the Button like:     mButton.setText(mEdittext.getText());

Comment: please check my edits. I'm using dialogbox in which I'm providing EditText, but still after rename button when I reopen application the button label is still set to "New".

Comment: Yes, because you set the value of the Button to "New" every time you start, if you want to save all the time whats the value of the Button  is you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: can you please tell me how it can be done if possible

Comment: See my Answer to this Question which is create now

Comment: i'm not able to get actually where your answer is.

Comment: showing error "getText cannot be resolved or is not a field" so I used getText() and cast "myButton.getText()" to string then it is showing error

Comment: mButton.getText().toString()

Comment: after restarting application all buttons have same label like- three buttons have label test1, test2, test3 and after restarting app all buttons have label test3

Comment: yes i've uninstalled application and also tried clearing data but still same result.

Comment: Yes, it because of the uninstallation, if you unstall your app or clean the datas the shared preferences will also cleaned

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic way to set label name to TextView**.

```
String[] buttonName = {"new","click","mouse","clothing"};

mButton.setText(buttonName[1]);  // here you can replace 1 with 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 as per your requirement.
```